# searching for EXACT string with spaces in . txt file from C program

Tags: c, file, strstr

```
struct Book {
        char *title;
        char *authors; 
        unsigned int year; 
        unsigned int copies; 
};


int existance_of_book(char title[])
{
    char string[30];
    ptr_to_library = fopen("library.txt", "r");

  if(ptr_to_library == NULL)
  {
    printf("\nERROR: cannot open file\n");
    return -1;
  }

    while (fgets(title, sizeof(title), ptr_to_library) != NULL)
  {
    if(strstr(string, title)!=0)
    {
      printf("book found\n");
      return 1;
    }
  }
    return 0;
}
```

**I am Trying to search for a string in a file, but since the string I will be searching for has a space in it this function is unable to find the string.  this function will also find a match if for example the string in the .txt file reads "hello", and the string entered in the function is "he". Is there a way to search for the exact string in a file even if there are spaces**

Comment: Error messages belong on stderr and should be informative: `if(ptr_to_library == NULL) { perror("library.txt"); ...`

Comment: The string "hello" indeed contains the string "he", so you should expect a match.  If you want to see if the string " he " is in the text, you should search for " he " instead of "he".  If you want to match any word boundary (eg, punctuation or beginning/end of line), you'll need to add some logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strstr` to find the sub-string.
Check that the sub-string is either at the beginning of the line or is preceded by punctuation or whitespace.
Also check that the sub-string is either at the end of the line or trailed by punctuation or whitespace.
If `fgets` is used to obtain the sub-string to find, be sure to use `strcspn` to remove the trailing newline. In the line from the file, the trailing newline should not matter, but this code uses `strcspn` to remove it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE 1024

int main ( void) {
    char find[SIZE] = "he";
    char line[SIZE] = "";
    char const *filename = "library.txt";
    char *match = NULL;
    FILE *pf = NULL;

    if ( NULL == ( pf = fopen ( filename, "r"))) {
        perror ( filename);
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int length = strlen ( find);

    while ( fgets ( line, SIZE, pf)) {//read lines until end of file
        line[strcspn ( line, "\n")] = 0;//remove newline
        char *temp = line;
        while ( ( match = strstr ( temp, find))) {//look for matches
            if ( match == line //first of line
            || ispunct ( (unsigned char)*(match - 1))
            || isspace ( (unsigned char)*(match - 1))) {
                if ( 0 == *(match + length)//end of line
                || ispunct ( (unsigned char)*(match + length))
                || isspace ( (unsigned char)*(match + length))) {
                    printf ( "found %s in %s\n", find, line);
                    break;//found a match
                }
            }
            temp = match + 1;//advance temp and check again for matches.
        }
    }

    fclose ( pf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have spaces in `fopen ( filename`?